# Attempt to de-reference a null object - list get set

Tags: apex, null-pointer

I try to add objects from 'accbetween' to 'idlist' (see the code below):

```
public class SearchTestApex {

    public list <Fund__c> idlist {get;set;}

    public list <Fund__c> accbetween  = new list<Fund__c>();

    public String idsaved {get;set;}

    public String searchKey {get;set;}

    public SearchTestApex( ) {
    }

    public void search(){

        String searchquerybetween='SELECT Id, Product__r.Id, Product__r.Name, Date__c FROM Fund__c WHERE Code__c LIKE \'%'+searchKey+'%\' ORDER BY Product__r.Id, Date__c DESC';

        accbetween= Database.query(searchquerybetween);

        //Then, I simply try to add the first value of accbetween to idlist:

        idlist.add(accbetween[0]);

        }
    }
```

There is a VisualForce code which is supposed to display 'idlist' but it returns the error as follow:

**Attempt to de-reference a null object**

I assume I might have to initialize 'idlist' or there could be an incompatibility between these types of list. Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you never construct `idList`, so when you  call `idList.add(...)`, you are really calling `null.add(...)`. This situation leads to an attempt to de-reference a null variable.

If you want for some reason to only add one result from your SOQL to the list, then add `LIMIT 1` to your `String`, and simply assign the query result to your property.

```
String soql = 'SELECT ... FROM Fund__c WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1';
idList = Database.query(soql);
```

If you don't like that approach, then you should instead instantiate a new list:

```
List<Fund__c> records = Database.query(...);
idList = new List<Fund__c>();
idList.add(records[0]);
```

Comment: Hello Adrian and thank you for your answer. I wanna add more values to idlist but it was just a simple example to show that I don't know how to assign a value to this kind of list. Also, I understand your second solution could work but with this type of list I won't be able to call it in a Visualforce code, right?

Comment: What do you mean you wouldn't be able to call it in Visualforce? The only factor in whether or not you can access it there is that it has a pubic getter (e.g. `{ get; set; }`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not making myself clear. When I implement 'public list <Fund__c> idlist = new list<Fund__c>();' then, idlist.add(accbetween[0]); doesn't return any problem. The problem being that I cannot call idlist in a Visualforce environment.

Comment: That's because you changed the code in the wrong place and remove the very getter I mention above. You need to instantiate the list *within the method*, before adding elements to it.

Comment: So as far as I understood, I should get the code below - but it's not returning anything (there is no error displayed though).

Comment: `String searchquerybetween='...' //


List<Fund__c> accbetween= Database.query(searchquerybetween); //

List<Fund__c> idlist = new List<Fund__c>(); //
idlist.add(accbetween[0]);`

Comment: I declared the 'idlist' variable within the method but obviously, one needs to declare it before: `public list <Fund_Holdings__c> idlist {get;set;}`. It is now working. Thank you Adrian!

Answer (score 0):

i think `Database.query(searchquerybetween)` returns no records, so you have to check weather query returns records or not. please update search method with below code.

```
 public void search(){

    String searchquerybetween='SELECT Id, Product__r.Id, Product__r.Name, Date__c FROM Fund__c WHERE Code__c LIKE \'%'+searchKey+'%\' ORDER BY Product__r.Id, Date__c DESC';

    accbetween= Database.query(searchquerybetween);
     idlist = new List<Fund__c>();
    //Then, I simply try to add the first value of accbetween to idlist:
 if(accbetween.size() > 0){idlist.add(accbetween[0])};

    }
```

Comment: You're thinking of the wrong error.

Comment: thank you @sfdcfox to find my mistake. updated